# What is the most optimal way, for it, to go up by two?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What is the most optimal way, for it, to go up by two?

```
 function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1){
      var total=[];
      for(let i=start; i<=end;i+=step){
        total+=i;
      }
      return total;
    }
    console.log(range(0,20,2));
```

Comment: Change `1` to `2` ..? Notice, that this bi-directional loop doesn't actually work as it is. When `end` will be smaller than `start`, this will end up to not running at all (the condition is never true).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var start = 0; 
var end = 30; 
var step =2;
for(let i =start; i<=end; i+=step){
console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: thanks mate for answer. I know that i can do it like this, but i wanted to do it with for a lopp.